# Cannot log in into Ubuntu after an upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen

Today I cannot log into the GUI, but I can use the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) to log in as a user or as root, and I can login via ssh.

Under Natty, before the upgrade, I had set up Ubuntu to auto-login as a user.
On Friday autologin was working with 12.04. Today I am presented with the login screen for the first time. I am not prompted for the user id, just for a password.

```
    $ sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.1, UID=0 PID=1421
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loaded configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting seat
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting new display for automatic login as user mslinn
    [+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
    [+0.02s] DEBUG: X server :0 will replace Plymouth
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Launching process 1452: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
    [+0.04s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
    [+0.41s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1452
    [+0.41s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
    [+0.41s] DEBUG: Stopping Plymouth, X server is ready
    [+0.43s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
    [+0.43s] DEBUG: Automatically logging in user mslinn
    [+0.43s] DEBUG: Started session 1524 with service 'lightdm-autologin', username 'mslinn'
    [+0.49s] DEBUG: Session 1524 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
    [+0.49s] DEBUG: Autologin user mslinn authorized
    [+0.49s] DEBUG: Autologin using session xterm
    [+0.50s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
    [+0.50s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
    [+0.51s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
    [+0.51s] DEBUG: Writing /home/mslinn/.dmrc
    [+0.53s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
    [+0.57s] DEBUG: Starting session xterm as user mslinn
    [+0.57s] DEBUG: Session 1524 running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session xterm
    [+0.65s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
    [+0.65s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
    [+0.66s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
    [+0.89s] DEBUG: Session 1524 exited with return value 0
    [+0.97s] DEBUG: User session quit
    [+0.97s] DEBUG: Stopping display
    [+0.97s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1452
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Process 1452 exited with return value 0
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: X server stopped
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Display stopped
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Active display stopped, switching to greeter
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Switching to greeter
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
    [+2.20s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
    [+2.21s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
    [+2.21s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
    [+2.21s] DEBUG: Launching process 1758: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
    [+2.21s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
    [+2.43s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1758
    [+2.43s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
    [+2.43s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
    [+2.43s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
    [+2.43s] DEBUG: Started session 1766 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
    [+2.61s] DEBUG: Session 1766 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
    [+2.61s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
    [+2.61s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
    [+2.66s] DEBUG: Session 1766 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
    [+3.12s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.1
    [+3.12s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
    [+3.12s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
    [+3.12s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
    [+3.12s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter display being switched from
    [+3.91s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for mslinn
    [+3.91s] DEBUG: Started session 2219 with service 'lightdm', username 'mslinn'
    [+3.99s] DEBUG: Session 2219 got 1 message(s) from PAM
    [+3.99s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

I tried deinstalling and reinstalling `lightdm`, but that did not help.

I have 3 virtualized Ubuntu systems; two of them have this problem. What should I do?

Comment: You said you had Natty before the upgrade to Precise. Did you upgrade to Oneiric and then Precise, or did you somehow upgrade directly from Natty to Precise (for example, by manually editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`), which is unsupported and which is liable to cause serious problems?

Comment: As an unrelated matter, [if you don't mind](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3204/should-really-good-detailed-me-too-answers-have-their-content-merged-into-the), I'll edit in the information from [this "me too" answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/141424/22949) (making clear that it applies to that user and not to your system), in case that helps in working on the problem. (Then that answer can be [removed](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion), which it [should be](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3024/should-i-flag-me-too-answers) because it's not actually an attempt to answer the question.)

Comment: Yes, Natty -> Oneiric -> Precise

Answer (score 1):

What I did to resolve this issue was to remove and reinstall lightdm and ubuntu-desktop.  Fixed the problem right away. You might have to make sure that you remove the cached package and make sure it downloads a fresh version from the repository.

Comment: I typed:
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/{light*,ubuntu*};
sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop

Comment: No desktop appeared, even after rebooting. I think I'm going backwards.

Comment: Can't figure this out. At this point I'm giving up and reinstalling. Disappointed :(